# Matching all nodes related to a set of other nodes - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm just getting started with neo4j and would like some help trying to solve a problem.

I have a set of `Questions` that require information (`Slots`) to answer them.

The rules of the graph (i.e. the `Slots` `required` for each `Question`) are shown below:

[Graph diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk75f.png)

In a scenario in which  I have a set of slots e.g. [`Slot A`, `Slot B`] I want to be able to check all `Questions` that the `Slots` are related to e.g. [`Question 1` , `Question 2`].

I then want to be able to check for which of the `Questions` all `required` `Slots` are available, e.g. [`Question 1`]

Is this possible, and if so how should I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Some data fixtures :

```
CREATE (q1:Question {name: "Q1"})
CREATE (q2:Question {name: "Q2"})
CREATE (s1:Slot {name: "Slot A"})
CREATE (s2:Slot {name: "Slot B"})
CREATE (s3:Slot {name: "Slot C"})
CREATE (q1)-[:REQUIRES]->(s1)
CREATE (q1)-[:REQUIRES]->(s2)
CREATE (q2)-[:REQUIRES]->(s1)
CREATE (q2)-[:REQUIRES]->(s3)
```

Find questions related to a slots list :

```
MATCH p=(q:Question)-[:REQUIRES]->(slot)
WHERE slot.name IN ["Slot A", "Slot B"]
RETURN p
```

[image]

Then, find questions related to a slot list, and return a boolean if the slot list contains all required slots for a question :

```
MATCH p=(q:Question)-[:REQUIRES]->(slot)
WHERE slot.name IN ["Slot A", "Slot B"]
WITH q, collect(slot) AS slots
RETURN q, ALL(x IN [(q)-[:REQUIRES]->(s) | s] WHERE x IN slots)

╒═════════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"q"          │"ALL(x IN [(q)-[:REQUIRES]->(s) | s] WHERE x IN slots)"│
╞═════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Q1"}│true                                                   │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Q2"}│false                                                  │
└─────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

A bit of explanation on that part `ALL(x IN [(q)-[:REQUIRES]->(s) | s] WHERE x IN slots)`

the [ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/index.html#functions-all) predicate, will check that the condition for every value in a list is true, for example `ALL (x IN [10,20,30] WHERE x > 5)`

the [extract](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-extract) shortcut syntax, you pass a list, it returns a list of the extracted values, the syntax is `extract(x IN <LIST> | <key to extract>)` for example :

```
extract(x IN [{name: "Chris", age: 38},{name: "John", age: 27}] | x.age)

// equivalent to the shortcut syntax for extract, with square brackets

[x IN [{name: "Chris", age: 38},{name: "John", age: 27}] | x.age]
```

Will return `[38,27]`

Combining it now :

For every path, extract the Slot node

```
[(q)-[:REQUIRES]->(s) | s]

Returns 

[s1, s2]
```

Are every of s1 and s2, in the list of the slot nodes previously collected ?

```
ALL(x IN [(q)-[:REQUIRES]->(s) | s] WHERE x IN slots)

Return true or false
```

---

Return only the questions when true :

```
MATCH p=(q:Question)-[:REQUIRES]->(slot)
WHERE slot.name IN ["Slot A", "Slot B"]
WITH q, collect(slot) AS slots
WITH q WHERE ALL(x IN [(q)-[:REQUIRES]->(s) | s] WHERE x IN slots)
RETURN q
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Very helpful. One follow up - is there a way to return just the `Questions` that are returned as `TRUE`?